# Find all possible rational values of the parameter of a parametric cubic such that it is reducible

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory, factorization

Description:  Given the following parametric cubic polynomials ${E}^{3}
- 15\, {\beta}_{\pm}\, {E}^{2} - 3 \left({71\, {\beta}_{\pm}^{2} + 352\, {\beta}_{\mp}}\right) E 
+ 135\, {\beta}_{\pm} \left({5\, {\beta}_{\pm}^{2} - 32\, {\beta}_{\mp}}\right)$ where ${\beta}_{\pm} = 1 \pm \eta$, how do I find all possible rational values of $\eta$ such that this polynomial is reducible.

Background:  I have found 61 rational values of $\eta$ that factor these polynomials into a rational linear $E - p/q$ for integer $p$ and $q$ relatively prime and $q \ne 0$ times an irreducible quadratic of the form ${E}^{2} + a\, E + b$.  I do not know if there are an infinite number of such values and if not do I have the complete set.

Comment: I updated my posting and simplified the description for clarity.  Simply put I am looking for all the cases where these parametric cubics are reducible over rationals.

Comment: The curve is rational.

Comment: Yes I am looking for the rational points.

Comment: @LorenzMenke I said the curve is rational, as in parametrizable by rational functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reopened the question so I can write an answer, although my comment should have sufficed but I may not be getting my message across.

Anyway, let's use some sane variables ($x=\beta_{\pm},y = E$), so the polynomial is

$$y^3-15xy^2-3(71x^2+352x)y+135x(5x^2-32x)$$

Let's now replace $y$ by $xz$ and get

$$(z^3 - 15z^2 - 213z + 675)x^3 + (-1056z - 4320)x^2.$$

So you can pick any rational $z$ that you like, compute

$$x = (1056z + 4320)/(z^3 - 15z^2 - 213z + 675)$$

and if you replace the value of $x=\beta_{\pm}$ by what you computed, the resulting cubic in $E$ has a factor $E - xz$.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you get a different polynomial if you replace both $\beta_\pm$ and $\beta_\mp$ by the same variable $x$.

Comment: @j.c. Oh, I missed that, there are two different betas in the polynomial. I need to redo this. Thanks.

Comment: But what does it actually mean? I would understand $\beta_+ = 1 + \eta, \beta_- = 1 - \eta$ but I don't actually know the difference between $1 \pm \eta$ and $1 \mp \eta$.

Comment: I believe that there are two different polynomials under consideration, one where you always take the upper signs so that $\beta_\pm=\beta_+$ and $\beta_\mp=\beta_-$, and similarly, another polynomial corresponding to the lower signs.

Comment: @j.c. But then wouldn't changing $\eta$ to $-\eta$ switch between the two?

Comment: I agree; that's how I read the question as well.

Comment: Yes there are two such polynomials.  My notation was not very clear.  Take all upper or all lower signs for the two cases.  The above solution is essentially correct with a correction that the resulting polynomial in x is the form $a {x}^3 + b {x}^2 + c x$.  This factors as x times a quadratic.  Solving the quadratic results in a quartic discriminant.  This converts to an elliptic curve with a couple of torsion points.  There is one generator point hence an infinite number of solutions which is what I was looking for.  Thank you all for the suggestions on the original algebraic manipulation.